# Download file in memory without saving it on disk Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an external link where the XLS file is stored. I need to download it **in memory, without saving it on disk**, read information from it and print that info to the console, so I don't need file after that.
The second issue that I've been struggling with - I can't transform that file to some Java Object.
I'm using `WebClient` from the `Spring WebFlux` library and don't know to which type I can transform the response. When I try to transform it into `ByteArrayInputStream`, `ByteArrayOutputStream` or `ByteArrayResource` I'm getting an error:
`org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8' not supported for bodyType...`

When I test an external link with Postman - I can see that it has a header with Content-Type application/vnd.ms-excel

Example with my code below:

```
ByteArrayResource xlsResponse = webClientBuilder.build().get()
                .uri(xlsLink)
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/vnd.ms-excel")
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=file.xls")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(ByteArrayResource.class)
                .block();
```

**UPDATE**
**RestTemplate** solved this problem. Just download it into byte array with next lines of code:
 `byte[] fileBytes = restTemplate.getForObject(xlsLink, byte[].class);`

But I'm still wondering how to do it with **WebClient**.